# How to create a receiver application in .NET that would accept messages or requests from ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net, tcplistener, pnrp

First of all thanks for taking the time to read my question. Here is what I am trying to accomplish followed by what I have so far on this.

What I want to do is create a Windows application (or server of sorts) that would listen for requests from an ASP.NET application. The windows application would be installed and would listen for messages from ASP.NET application and then do some processing. The flow is like this:

A user downloads the desktop application and registers their IP address on my web site. After downloading the desktop app, the ASP.NET application can then send requests to that particular desktop client for further processing. I think further processing is independent of the resolution in this case that's why i have skipped over details on what processing would be done. But if you think it is important, please let me know and I will add those details as well.

I have looked into creating a TCP server that would listen for requests. Because the user has already registered their IP address on my web site, my web site assigns them a unique identifier and stores the ID alongwith IP address in database. Now, the ASP.NET site can send requests to that desktop application.

I have looked into creating a TCP server for this purpose. While researching I also came across PNRP and it seems something like what I am trying to do.

Can you guys recommend some solutions or where I should be looking at for this scenario? Should I create a simple TCPLISTENER or may be go with PNRP approach? Or something else?

The basic requirement is for a web application to be able to communicate with a desktop application. The web application would be servicing numerous users and each user would have a desktop application installed. Which user for which desktop client question would be addressed by the web application that would maintain a database of unique user id's and their corresponding IP Address.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, take firewalling/NAT into account.  It might be easier for the client application to poll the server (initiate the connection) otherwise you open a can of worms by trying to have a remotely-accessible server in your user's computer without having to do some very manual configurations on the user's networking equipment.

Once you have that part sorted out, what I used in your situation was .NET Remoting. At the time WCF had not come out and when it did it was to crippled for my needs.  TCP IP sockets were too raw (I had to write too much code) and so Remoting solved my problem ideally (a hand full lines of code to set up the connection, and everything was automatic from there on).

**EDIT:** I use an excellent third party library that makes Remoting even more flexible (flexible enough that I am still waiting for WCF to catch up with the featureset so that I stop using Remoting, and no luck yet!).  Check out http://www.genuinechannels.com/ to see all the features they have.  It includes making calls from server to client, and that sounds exactly like what you need to do.  Check it out.

Comment: Hey thanks for your input. I am going to look into this and come back to you. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .NET remoting or a web-service in the desktop app. Use WCF or WSE for the latter. You can use COM to add windows firwall rules.

Comment: Hey thanks for your input. Can you point me to some links where i can learn more about this web-service in desktop app? If I am not mistaken, the web service should be on the desktop and the ASP.NET application should contact that web service? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, but you can use WCF in .NET 3.5 (webservice everywhere) or you can use Web Service Enhancements (.NET 2.0). This link here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=018a09fd-3a74-43c5-8ec1-8d789091255d&displaylang=en and this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Enhancements Tutorials you find via google.

Comment: thanks! What about PNRP approach? Do you think it is suitable or this? Basically, I was looking into PNRP and it looks close to what I want to do. However, I am not sure whether it would work in my scenario or not. I need to find out whether PNRP COULD WORK HERE OR NO, before I attempt further research on PNRP and start to learn it.  Any ideas?